# Are the head and tail of a Set guaranteed to be mutually exclusive?

Tags: scala, recursion, scala-collections

The [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.Set@head%3aA) says that `Set.head` returns the "first" item, and `.tail` returns "all but the first".* Since a `Set` doesn't really have a "first" item, the documentation warns that without an ordered type, you might get a different result on different runs. But are you guaranteed that the tail won't include the head?

The reason I'm asking is I'm wondering if it's OK to recurse down a `Set` like this:

```
def recurse(itemsToExamine: Set[Item], acc: Result): Result =
  if (itemsToExamine.isEmpty) acc
  else {
    val item = itemsToExamine.head
    recurse(
      item.spawnMoreItems ++ itemsToExamine.tail,
      acc.updatedFor(item))
  }
```

If that's legitimate, it would certainly be nicer than converting from `Set` to `Seq` and back in order to separate head and tail on each recursion.

---

*Actually, it says "selects the first item" and "selects all but the first item". I assume that "selects" is just a poor choice of word. If there's a reason for saying "selects" rather than "returns", please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% sure about this, because I haven't looked too much at the implementation, but for any `HashSet` there's an implicit ordering based on the `hashCode` (of type `Int`) of the values that are already in the `Set`.

That means that for any `Set` instance, calls to `head` and `tail` will respect that ordering, so it won't be the same element. Even more, successive iteration through the elements of a given `Set` instance should yield the elements in the same order, because the `Set` is immutable.

The takeaway is that while the ordering is unknown, there is one for any instance, which may change as soon as you add (mutably or immutably) a new element to the `Set`.

Answer (score 4):

Relying on `head` and `tail` on `Set` (without ordering) is risky at best.

In your case, simply get an `Iterator` from your `Set` first with `theSet.toIterator`, then recurse over the iterator. The iterator guarantees that the first element will be different from the others, of course.

Comment: What's the equivalent of `.tail` for an `Iterator`? `.toSet` after calling `.next`?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
val set = Set(1, 2, 3)
val head = set.head
val tail = set - head
```

This is guaranteed to keep them mutually exclusive.